# Facebook like button comment box

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

I am facing a problem with Facebook like button

1. crate a dynamic URL by appending  id
2. apply this URL to Facebook like button
3. when user press like button it show blank comment box with outdata in og:meta tags
4. after refresh the page and click like button it show the og:meta tags details

I am using XFBML  version and when i put generated URL in Facebook debugger it show correct information.

Comment: have you tried to run the url's through the debugger? doing so will force facebook to scrape the page. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Yes i tried that and it show correct details. But when user visit the page and press like it give blank comment box.Then refresh the page and unlike it and press like it show correct details.